# Error on Convert.ToDateTime function, having error as "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, datetime

Here is my code:

```
private void GenerateExcelDataToday()
{
    try
    {
        // Setting path for the Excel File
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath("~/Closure.xlsx"));

        if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xls")
        {
            oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
        }
        else if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xlsx")
        {
            oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
        }

        oledbConn.Open();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        oledbConn.Close();
    }

    ClosureReport();
}

private void ClosureReport()
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    cmd.Connection = oledbConn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Data$]";
    oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    oleda.Fill(ds);

    grvData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    grvData.DataBind();
    grvData.Visible = false;

    Day();
}

private void Day()
{
    DateTime Date = DateTime.Today;
    double G;

    for (int i = 0; i < grvData.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (grvData.Rows[i].Cells[22].Text == "AU")
        {
           G = (Date - Convert.ToDateTime(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text)).TotalDays;
           AUDay1.Text = Convert.ToString(G);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like the cells 3 Data is having error. I want to convert the string value into DateTime but it showing me error: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

The excel data is formatted at this : 4/1/2014  1:16:32 AM

How can I solve this?

Comment: It is not the string the `Convert.ToDateTime` fails on, right? Can you show us the string that generates exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `grvData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text` is  `4/1/2014 1:16:32 AM`, it doesn't have a [*standart date and time format*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That's why your `Convert.ToDateTime` method throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.FormatException.aspx).

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to parse your custom formatted string.

```
string s = "4/1/2014 1:16:32 AM";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
     Console.WriteLine(date);
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Your string is not valid.");
}
```

Output will be;

```
4/1/2014 1:16:32 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/Mz6kcG)</kbd>.

For more information, take a look at;

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 G = (Date - DateTime.ParseExact(grvData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text).ToString().Trim(), "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
string strDate = "4/1/2014 1:16:32 AM";
DateTime datDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, new string[] { "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt" },
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine(datDate);
}
```

As per your code:

```
 ..................................................
    for (int i = 0; i < grvData.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
     if (grvData.Rows[i].Cells[22].Text == "AU")
     {
     string strDate = grvData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
     DateTime presenetDate;           
     if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, new string[] { "MM/d/yyyy h:m:s tt" },
                            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
     {
       G = (Date - presenetDate).TotalDays;
           AUDay1.Text = Convert.ToString(G);
     }
     else
     {
       AUDay1.Text = "Not a Valid date";
     }
   .......................................
```